# Getting the body in a Post request with Maru framework

Tags: elixir, maru

I am new to Elixir.
I am sending a POST request with a application/json body. I am using postman. When I send a json body payload with a POST request I get a server error. i.e:

```
%Plug.Parsers.ParseError{
  exception: %UndefinedFunctionError{
    arity: 1,
    exports: nil,
    function: :decode!,
    module: Poison,
    reason: nil
  },
  plug_status: 400
}
```

Below is the request and the code of the request and the route processing it. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

BTW: When I am sending the message with Content-Type: text/plain the request works but I cant find the body anywhere.

What I want is to get the JSON in the body param.

```
OST /api/v1/users/abs22/devices/ytuh48753hhkjfo/power HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8880
-X-App-Id: Balalalal
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0eaf390c-37e5-88db-c1c7-e05c7dbfbf01

{
    "device": {
        "power_on": true
    }
}
```

The router looks like this:

```
  namespace :devices do

    params do
      group :device, type: Json |> List do
        optional :power_on, type: Boolean
      end
    end
    get do
      conn
      |> json(
        %{
          devices: [
                   %{
                     uuid: :abcs,
                     name: :string,
                     description: :string,
                     is_online: true,
                     is_on: false,
                     has_current: true,
                     site_id: nil,
                     user_id: conn.params["user_id"]

                   },
                   %{
                     uuid: :abcf,
                     name: :string,
                     description: :string,
                     is_online: true,
                     is_on: false,
                     has_current: true,
                     site_id: nil,
                     user_id: conn.params["user_id"]

                   }
                 ]
               }
      )
    end

    post do
      conn
      |> json(
        %{
          device: %{
          uuid: :abcf,
          name: :string,
          description: :string,
          is_online: true,
          is_on: false,
          has_current: true,
          site_id: nil,
          user_id: conn.params["user_id"]
          }
        }
      )
    end

    route_param :device_id, type: String do
      get do
        conn
        |> json(
          %{
            device: %{
              uuid: params[:device_id],
              name: :string,
              description: :string,
              is_online: true,
              is_on: false,
              has_current: true,
              site_id: nil,
              user_id: conn.params["user_id"],
              timers: [
                %{
                  uuid: :string,
                  description: "10 byte representing switch, week, days, time on, time off",
                  kind: "reccuring"

                },
                %{
                  uuid: :string,
                  description: "10 byte representing switch, week, days, time on, time off",
                  kind: "countdown"

                },
                %{
                  uuid: :string,
                  description: "10 byte representing switch, week, days, time on, time off",
                  kind: "pattern"

                },
              ]
            }
          }
        )
      end

      put do
        conn
        |> json(
          %{
            device: %{
              uuid: params[:device_id],
              name: :change1,
              description: :change2,
              is_online: true,
              is_on: false,
              has_current: true,
              site_id: nil,
              user_id: conn.params["user_id"]
            }
          }
        )
      end

      delete do
        conn
        |> json(
          %{
            device: %{
              uuid: params[:device_id],
              name: :string,
              description: :string,
              is_online: true,
              is_on: false,
              has_current: true,
              site_id: nil,
              user_id: conn.params["user_id"]
            }
          }
        )
      end

      post :power do
        conn
        |> IO.inspect
        |> json(
          %{
            device: %{
              uuid: params[:device_id],
              name: :string,
              description: :string,
              is_online: true,
              is_on: true,
              has_current: true,
              site_id: nil,
              user_id: conn.params["user_id"]
            }
          }
        )

      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have Poison module in your dependencies? Looks like the parser couldn’t find the Poison module as it tries to decode the request. You can check iex to see if Poison is loaded when your app starts

Comment: @Badu you are correct. I have Jason as the parser. Changing it to Jason fixed that. Thanks